# Possible to configure Dragonfly-Gem w/Rails3 to force convert all uploads to image/jpeg?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, dragonfly-gem

I've been reading through the DragonFly docs and I think the before_serve clause of DragonFly's configuration is probably where I need to focus, perhaps by setting up some sort of

```
convert to jpeg if not jpeg
```

logic there.  Or is there a much quicker/simpler way?

Comment: Why not try carrierwave or paperclip for that matter

Comment: @Viren It mostly comes down to preferences/experience in my shop.  We've been using Paperclip for a long time but could really benefit from the just in time processing with DragonFly.  Otherwise I haven't tried CourierWave and perhaps the next rails project I'll give it a spin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry just saw this. if you want to convert the ORIGINAL to a jpeg then use a model after_assign callback - see http://markevans.github.com/dragonfly/file.Models.html#Callbacks
you'd do

```
image_accessor :avatar do
  after_assign{|a| a.jpg! unless a.format == :jpg }
end
```

though actually you don't even need the "unless" bit because doing .jpg! on a jpeg won't do anything

Comment: Well, can't get much more authoritative then the DragonFly creator, thanks.